# Make div consists of 2 smaller divs responsive

Tags: css

So I have this `div` [right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gud8L.jpg) which consists of 2 smaller divs which is `leftdiv` and `rightdiv`. How do I make this responsive where the `rightdiv` will move to the bottom of the `leftdiv` when the screen size is smaller? Also how do I maintain the distance between those words in `leftdiv` so that they wont cramp up together when the screen size becomes smaller.

The css code is for the wording in the `leftdiv` for `price,quantity,max winning and marketcap`

```js
.tokenDetails{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    padding: 15px 0;
    justify-content: left;
    .tPrice{
        margin-left: 47px;
        width: 220px;
    }
    .tTotalRaise{
        width: 180px;
    }
    .ticketAllocation{
        width: 180px;
    }
    .tMarketCap{
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should post your full code for others to go through

Comment: You should also show your markup. We can't figure anything out with just css, please post your HTML/JSX code

Comment: It would also be worth tagging the question with the CSS pre-processor you are using.

Comment: You should google [css media queries](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+media+queries) and also check [the flexbox](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+flex).